# Aggregate concatenate jsonb arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

Having a table named `example_table` with one column named `example_column` of type JSONB and every value in the column being an array.

Having the values in 2 rows be: [1, 2] and [3]

How can I aggregate-concatenate the values in `example_column`?

The result should be: [1, 2, 3]

I tried using:

```
select json_agg(example_column) from example_table
```

but that returns `[[1, 2,], [3]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements(example_column),`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) example:

```
with example_table(example_column) as (
values
    (jsonb '[1, 2]'),
    (jsonb '[3]')
)

select jsonb_agg(value)
from example_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(example_column) 

jsonb_agg 
-----------
 [1, 2, 3]
(1 row)
```

Update. You can define the sort order of aggregated elements and/or remove duplicates, e.g.:

```
with example_table(id, example_column) as (
values
    (1, jsonb '[1, 2]'),
    (2, jsonb '[3]'),
    (3, jsonb '[3, 1]')
)

select 
    jsonb_agg(value order by id) as agg1,
    jsonb_agg(value order by value) as agg2,
    jsonb_agg(distinct value order by value) as agg3
from example_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(example_column) 

      agg1       |      agg2       |   agg3    
-----------------+-----------------+-----------
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 1] | [1, 1, 2, 3, 3] | [1, 2, 3]
(1 row)
```

Comment: it actually returns `[3, 1, 2]` instead of `[1, 2, 3]` but for my use case it does what I need

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do that a lot, you could create your own aggregate for this:

```
create function combine_jsonb_arrays(p_array_1 jsonb, p_array_2 jsonb) 
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_agg(t.val order by t.val)
  from (
    select *
    from jsonb_array_elements(p_array_1) as x1(val)
    union all
    select *
    from jsonb_array_elements(p_array_2) as x2(val)
  ) t;
$$
language sql;

create aggregate jsonb_elements_agg(jsonb)
(
  sfunc = combine_jsonb_arrays,
  stype = jsonb
);
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select jsonb_elements_agg(example_column)
from example_table;
```